# Close programmatically an overlay MUI CSS

Tags: css, material-design

How to close an overlay created with MUI CSS ?

For now, I see that :

```
mui.overlay('off', modalEl);
```

But it looks ugly since modalEl has to be global to be reachable in the function that'll trigger the closing of the overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same issue, yes the way to go was to declare your modal global in the view, using to hide the modal

```
mui.overlay('off', modalEl)
```

using to display the modal

```
mui.overlay('on', modalEl);
```